# How to toggle auto open run tab when running application in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to make Android Studio toggle auto open the run tab when running an app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations` -> select miscellaneous tab and check `Show logcat automatically`.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

1. Tap on Modify run configuration option on the left side of Run tool window
   [image: Modify run configuration]
2. Untick Activate tool window option at the bottom
   [image: Activate tool window]