# How to prevent Android Studio to automatically switch to "Run" tab when I start the app

Tags: android-studio

With some version of Android Studio it started to automatically switch to Run tab

[image]

when I start the app

[image]

which is very annoying, I want to keep the Logcat tab always

How to disable such behaviour?

Even after I did this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957258/7767664 I still can see that Android Studio first switches to Run tab and then to Logcat tab, this is stupid...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to your Run/Debug configuration and Uncheck Activate tool window at the bottom. This gets rid of the Run tab. This works.

Comment: Finally, Thanks!) p.s.: this is at the Debugger tab

Comment: This is an asinine thing they added to Android Studio. Let me have whatever tab I want to have open for petes sake.

Comment: @PanamaJack For real...they always forcing this garbage on us

Answer (score 23):

Just to complement AJITHA VIJAYAKUMAR's answer.. Here's a screenshot from the steps:

[image: Instructions]

Comment: I don't see this setting in Flamingo

Comment: @OlehRomanenko it's there. I'm using Flamingo and had to do the same thing.  Once the edit window is open you have to scroll down.

Comment: Also need to set this configuration every time for a new project.

Comment: @PanamaJack scrolling down....I think you saved me another 8 years of manually closing the tool window on each run

Answer (score 8):

With the new UI in Android Studio Giraffe, a lot has changed.

Now, the easiest way to disable the bottom tool window (which shows build, run, logcat logs, etc) is,

1. Go to `Run/Debug Configurations` (the green section with your module name in the Main Toolbar at the top)
2. Go to `Edit Configurations...`
3. Scrolldown to the bottom of the Run/Debug Configurations window.
4. Deselect the `Activate tool window` checkbox and click OK

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to scroll down on the General tab to find that Activate tool window checkbox you need to disable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Logcat` to always be visible, disable `Activate tool window` from previous answers, then check `Show logcat automatically` from the `Miscellaneous` tab

[image: Android studio Show always logcat automatically]